# SpringBoot Postgresql Driver issue

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot with Intellij IDEA. I believe I have all the dependencies needed. Still I keep getting PostgreSQL driver not found error.
Here are the dependencies in the Gradle File.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Comment: Which of those dependencies do you believe include the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, and why do you believe that? Or more specifically, why do you believe it includes the *PostgreSQL* driver, and not a driver for some other database?

Comment: I got this list from Spring.io starter kit. I thought that they must have included these basic pre-requisites in the JPA starter lib that I had. I 'm surprised that they didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependency also:

```
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.1'
```

After inclusion of the dependency in the gradle.build file also include the following lines in your Application.properties file to inform the application where the PostgreSQL server is and what are the credentials to access the database

> ```
> spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
> spring.datasource.username=postgres
> spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
> ```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have solved that problem, let me look into the problem with JDBC URL and then I should be good to do. Thanks again.

Comment: Gasbos May I know why we needed the last property and its value create-drop.

Comment: You can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are none, validate, update, create, and create-drop. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded. It defaults to create-drop if no schema manager has been detected or none in all other cases. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Thanks , let me check the documentation.

Comment: `runtimeOnly` dependency should be enough.